# eclipse add jar source attachment

Tags: eclipse, jar

In eclipse, java build path, I have added a new jar and attach source jar, then when I right click the new jar class method (WordUtils.capitalizeFully(....) and select open declaration, it can jump to the WordUtils.class properly, but it still prompt "'commons-text-1.9.jar' is missing a valid source attachment.....", why?

I already attach the source jar and it can jump properly to WordUtils.class source, why still show this message?

the related entry in .classpath is

```
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/commons-text-1.9.jar" sourcepath="lib/commons-text-1.9-sources.jar">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="javadoc_location" value="jar:platform:/resource/EXM/lib/commons-text-1.9-javadoc.jar!/"/>
            <attribute name="org.eclipse.jst.component.dependency" value="/WEB-INF/lib"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/commons-lang3-3.11.jar">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="org.eclipse.jst.component.dependency" value="/WEB-INF/lib"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: You seem to have an empty "External Location" selected in the Source Attachment Configuration dialog rather than "Workspace Location"

Comment: the source jar is my workspace, so I choose workspace location

Comment: Yes, but it looks to me like the check box for External Location is selected. Select the Workspace Location check box. Or show us the contents of the `.classpath` file for the project which will make what is being used absolutely clear.

Comment: add .classpath information